# autocomplete api php conversion error

Tags: php, api, autocomplete

I am trying to use api.autocomplete.com api

```
http://api.autocompleteplus.com/?l=en&c=us&q=f
```

this returns the following json(maybe) code..

```
try {acp_new({ query: "f","items":["facebook", "fandango", "fedex", "fedex tracking", "firefox", "food network", "ford", "forever 21", "fox", "fox news"]});} catch (e){}
```

I do not what the hell with this code or api..
I am not able to print these keywords in php

See, I made this code

```
 <?php

$url="http://api.autocompleteplus.com/?q=abc&l=ar&c=in&callback=acp_new&o=1";
$get=file_get_contents($url);
$get=json_decode($get,true);

foreach($get as $data) 
{
$see=$data['items'];
 echo "$see"; 
}
?>
```

I dont know what's wrong with this code or what's wrong i have done above...

Somebody please help me.

I am getting error.. What ever i am trying to do with this code i am getting error.

Comment: Well, *what* error are you getting?

Comment: @Pekka웃 i am getting this error Warning: Illegal string offset 'items' in D:\xampp\htdocs\search\auto.php on line 10
a
Notice: Undefined index: items in D:\xampp\htdocs\search\auto.php on line 10

Comment: Any idea how to fix it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did a print_r of your $get the structure you are getting is different and the processing you are doing in for each loop is different

```
<?php

   $url="http://api.autocompleteplus.com/?q=abc&l=ar&c=in&callback=acp_new&o=1"    ;
   $get=file_get_contents($url);
   $get=json_decode($get,true);

   print_r($get);
   die();

  foreach($get as $data)
  {
  $see=$data['items'];
   echo "$see";
  }
 ?>
```

This provides an out as below

```
Array
(
    [0] => abc
    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => abc
            [1] => abc news
            [2] => abc full tv schedule
            [3] => abcgames.com
            [4] => abc tv news
            [5] => abc games
            [6] => abc shows
            [7] => abc sports
            [8] => abc tv
            [9] => abc radio
        )

)
```

The above output clearly says that there is no offset in the array called items,

so its just an integer indexed array , but with in the foreach loop you are trying to access $data['items'] which does not exists  hence you are getting an error as

PHP Warning:  Illegal string offset 'items'

So the correct script would be

```
 <?php

  $url="http://api.autocompleteplus.com/?q=abc&l=ar&c=in&callback=acp_new&o=1"    ;
   $get=file_get_contents($url);
   $get=json_decode($get,true);

   foreach($get[1] as $data)
   {

   echo "$data";
  }
  ?>
```

Hope this helps

Comment: @Kapil in php print_r is used to inspect the contents of any object while debugging , so its just for debugging the problem actual I posted the actual script that you need to use

Comment: @Kapil print_r also helps you to understand the structure of data you are getting from the API so based on that you can process the data what you got from the API with in the For loop

Comment: Yes i got it Man. Thanks for the help. This is a right answer.